# odbc error connecting mysql: "sql server does not exist or access denied"

Tags: mysql, odbc, microsoft-access

For a few weeks now I have been trying to create an odbc connection with microsoft access and a mysql database on webhost server with no luck whatsoever.

I have no problem connecting to the database with workbench or other third party software's but they don't do what I need.

When I try to connect I receive these errors.

```
Connection Failed;
SQLState:'01000'
SQL Server Error:10060
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]ConnectionOpen
(Connect()).
Connection failed;
SQLState:'08001'
SQL Server Error:17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]SQL Server does not exist or access denied
```

I have been searching forums for possible solutions but none have worked. I have made very little progress.

Really hope someone here can help me.

Comment: `Server does not exist or access denied` - Have you verified the server name or ip address that you're trying to connect to? Have you verified the identity that you're trying to connect with? What have you tried and what were the results? Your question, as it stands, is poor. In fact, it really isn't a question, it's a statement. If you've put as much effort into solving your problem as you've put into this question then I'm not surprised that you haven't resolved it.

Comment: thanks joeqwerty for your response. Sorry I havent been very clear I am not very good at all this stuff. I have verified the server name. It connects fine with workbench. The website I am trying to connect to is on linux server, could thes be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does your SQL server config allow access from the host/IP that is your linux server? If you can connect fine with workbench (presumably from another PC/host/network, then you need to look at your user permissions and where you are allowed to connect from.

Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html) page as it gives the config for setting/checking the host part.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an ODBC driver for Microsoft SQL Server, to connect to a MySQL server instance.  This will never work.  They just don't speak the same language!

You need an ODBC driver for MySQL, like [the ones from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-mysql/).